# Suppliers for plain flavoured pop rocks

Tags: pop-rocks

Does anyone know of suppliers that I can buy plain flavoured pop rocks. The grocery stores around here only sell the fruit flavoured variety. (From Vancouver BC)

Answer (score 5):

ok, some kind of weird internet zeitgeist going on, but Instructables.com had a post up this morning on how to make your own: http://www.instructables.com/id/Pop-Rocks/

now you can make your own!

Comment: oh perfect! ... I just looked up the ingredients and all those are easy enough to find.  Thanks for the info! Can't wait to try it out.

Comment: you're welcome! i'm tempted to try them out myself. i love those things. : )

Answer (score 3):

www.chefrubber.com  look for pastry rocks

www.willpowder.com  look for will poppers

just purchased this myself...good luck and have fun